# Javascript Read data from spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I am using a HTML form to get data from google spreadsheet.

I need to get the row where SerNo= 2 (or any specific number)
I am looping through the sheet and trying to get the values as below - but it does nothing

ex:
SerNo  Col2
2      Option1
3      Option2
4      Option3

So,if SerNo=2 ...I want to get Option1.
This has 24 columns so i have used the getLastColumn

```
{function getDataRows_(ss, sheetname) {
 var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

var lr= sh.getLastRow();
for(var i=1;i<=lr;i++){
var SerNo1 = sh.getRange(i, 2).getValue();  
if(SerNo1==SerNo){                            

return sh.getRange(i, 2, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
}
}
}
```

----edit---
I have posted the whole code I use since it looks like i am filtering records at the wrong place

```
function read_value(request,ss){


var output  = ContentService.createTextOutput(),
  data    = {};

  var sheet="sheet1";


data.records = readData_(ss, sheet);

 var callback = request.parameters.callback;

 if (callback === undefined) {
  output.setContent(JSON.stringify(data));
 } else {
 output.setContent(callback + "(" + JSON.stringify(data) + ")");
 }
 output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);

 return output;
 }


function readData_(ss, sheetname, properties) {

if (typeof properties == "undefined") {
properties = getHeaderRow_(ss, sheetname);
properties = properties.map(function(p) { return p.replace(/\s+/g, '_'); });
}

var rows = getDataRows_(ss, sheetname),
  data = [];

for (var r = 0, l = rows.length; r < l; r++) {
var row     = rows[r],
    record  = {};

  for (var p in properties) {
  record[properties[p]] = row[p];
  }

  data.push(record);

}
return data;
}

function getDataRows_(ss, sheetname) {
var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

return sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() -1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();

}



function getHeaderRow_(ss, sheetname) {
var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

return sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];  
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

One thing I would recommend is to not retrieve the data on row at a time; in other words retrieve all of the data that you want to search through into an array (i.e. row 1 through last row) and then test each row of the array, looking for your value.

Comment: ---edit--- I have posted the whole code I use since it looks like i am filtering records at the wrong place-- can you help me correct it please